# How to get a file with the introns of a gene?

Tags: gene, reference-genome, bed

I was able to get the exons of a particular gene as a fasta file from the NCBI genome viewer. As for introns I only found a bed file that showed where the intron starts and ends, along with its direction. What tool do I use to get the exact sequence of these 11 introns using this bed file?
And is there a more direct way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First I edited the Chromosome column of the bed file from ncbi, because it contained the accession number instead of the chromosome. Then I used the getfasta tool of the bedtools utility.

`bedtools getfasta -fi input_genome_file.fa -fo output.fa -bed bed_file`

The output contained the introns in the format I wanted.
If anybody had a better way, feel free to post.

Comment: Hi @venkateshwar thank you for sharing this information. Could you just confirm that this is the answer to the question you posted (it looks like it)?

Comment: @M__ Ok I will.